# TFS Continuous integration except certain checkins from triggering build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have TFS continuous integration set up, where every check-in triggers a build. But I also want some scripts to automatically modify specific files as part of the build process. This causes a cascade of builds, because files modified by scripts cause another build to be queued. How do I enable continuous integration, but except some check-ins from triggering the build?

**UPDATE** [Solution is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2007/07/27/tfs-2008-how-to-check-in-without-triggering-a-build-when-using-continuous-integration.aspx): put the `***NO_CI***` into comments when checking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the way a Gated Build works it bypasses any configured CI by spending ##NOCI## or something similar to the checkin comment. I would think that you could do the same to bypass.

Switch to a Gated Build for one build and see the created comment tag.